# switch_console.c:1053 We've become an orphan, no more console for us

Tags: linux, docker, freeswitch

I installed the Freeswitch on Ubuntu Image in the Docker, referring to the documentation mentioned [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian#Debian-DebianPackage).

When I did the following:

```
Start FreeSWITCH
First Time

cd /usr/local/freeswitch/bin

./freeswitch
```

I got to the following screen on my command prompt.

[image]

And as the last line says, `[WARNING] switch_console.c:1053 We've become an orphan, no more console for us.`, something is wrong here I believe.

As per the documentation, I was expecting the prompt, like `freeswitch@domain>` .

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Upon researching this error I landed at the source file many times at different places, for example, one mentioned [here](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/src/switch_console.c)

Comment: what does your docker run command look like? You may need the -it flags to setup the console as interactive and TTY.

Comment: First I went into Ubuntu:14.10 image using `docker run -i -t Ubuntu:14.10 /bin/bash` and then I was working inside the Linux environment.

Comment: did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

If we look in the source code of Freeswitch, we see

```
    if (getppid() == 1) {
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_WARNING, "We've become an orphan, no more console for us.\n");
        break;
    }
```

We see that we had pid == 1, this mean that parent process for freeswitch is init process but we launched it in bash
docker run -it freeswitch_container bash

Problem described [here](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/)

To solve this you just need to run another bash in running bash, so it will have pid != 1.